# String Between Function?

Tags: c#, string

Is there a way to get the string between.. lets say quote "
The problem with using Indexof and substring is that it gets the first " and last " but not the pair. Like

> "Hello" "WHY ARE" "WWWWWEEEEEE"

It will get

> Hello" "WHY ARE" "WWWWWEEEEEE

I want it to get to array > Hello, WHY ARE, WWWWEEEEEE

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

```
StringCollection resultList = new StringCollection();
try 
{
    Regex regexObj = new Regex("\"([^\"]+)\"");
    Match matchResult = regexObj.Match(subjectString);

    while (matchResult.Success) 
    {
        resultList.Add(matchResult.Groups[1].Value);
        matchResult = matchResult.NextMatch();
    } 
}
catch (ArgumentException ex) 
{
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

If `subjectString` was *"Hello" "WHY ARE" "WWWWWEEEEEE"*, that should give you a list containing:

- Hello
- WHY ARE
- WWWWWEEEEEE

---

A more compact example which uses the static `Regex` class instead, and just writes the matches to console instead of adding to a collection:

```
var subject = "\"Hello\" \"WHY ARE\" \"WWWWWEEEEEE\"";
var match = Regex.Match(subject, "\"([^\"]+)\"");

while (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
    match = match.NextMatch();
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, you can simplify it by removing the try-catch though, since when run once you already know that the regular expression don't contain any syntax errors.

Comment: If you want the spaces inbetween as well you can just remove the quotes and the group and take the whole match. Replace `"([^"]+)"` with `[^"]+`, and `match.Groups[1].Value` with `match.Value`.

Answer (score 2):

```
string s = '"Hello" "WHY ARE" "WWWWWEEEEEE"'
string[] words = s.Split('"');
// words is now ["Hello", " ", "WHY ARE", " ", "WWWWWEEEEEE"]
```

If you don't want the empty strings, you can split by `'" "'`, in which case you will get `['"Hello', "WHY ARE", 'WWWWWEEEEEE"']`.

On the other hand, using regular expressions could be the best solution for what you want. I'm not a C# expert, so I can't give the code from the top of my head, but this is the regex you'll want to use: `"(.*?)"`

Comment: It won't work. It will have all things between the o" and "W also. I only want the HELLO, etc.

Comment: you should use `([^"]+)` instead of `(.*?)` because it is more efficient, and will skip the empty ones, like `""`

Comment: ([^"]+) is more efficient, that's true. But the OP didn't say he doesn't want to catch empty ones.

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = '"Hello" "WHY ARE" "WWWWWEEEEEE"
s.replace("\" \"", "!*!"); // custom seperator
s.Replace('"', string.empty);
string[] words = s.Split('!*!');
```

Should do the trick,

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: this would give [Hello, WHY, ARE, WWWWWEEEEEE]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [String.IndexOf(char value, int startIndex)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xkyx09y.aspx) method which has, as its parameter says, a start index from which the scan is started.

```
int start = 0;
do
{
  int i1 = s.IndexOf('=', start);
  if (i1 < 0) break;

  int i2 = s.IndexOf('=', i1 + 1);
  if (i2 < 0) break;

  yield return s.Substring(i1, i2 - i1);
  start = i2 + 1;
}
while (start < s.Length);
```